# How to display multiple strings one by one with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, string, display

So, what i want to make a simple web page that display multiple texts from an array one after one , I ve tried so many ways SetTimeout , Set interval and nothing work  **it give me only the last word like that the loop turn all times and give me the last result**

```
<h1 class="name" id="text"></h1> html code
<script>
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
var i  = 0 ;
setTimeout(function loop(){
do {
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = cars[i];
i++;
}
while (i < cars.length);  
},4000)
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many ways to do this. One is to use `setInterval` and iterate over the array of cars at each interval. And after the iteration go to the next value by incrementing the iterator with one.

The example below uses a *closure* to keep the iterator variable in its own scope.

```js
const cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
const textElement = document.getElementById("text");

function carDisplayer() {
  let i = 0;
  return function(cars) {
    let interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (i < cars.length) {
        textElement.textContent = cars[i];
        i++;
      } else {
        clearInterval(interval);
        i = 0;
     }
    }, 1000);
  }
}

let displayCars = carDisplayer();
displayCars(cars);
```

```html
<h1 class="name" id="text"></h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate the array and inside `forEach` callback use setTimeout.In that case there is no need of `do` & `while` loop.Since you want to display it once at a time with a delay , you need to change the timing value. You can do that by multiplying the index with constant time

```js
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
const element = document.getElementById("text");
cars.forEach((item, index) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    element.innerHTML = item;
  }, index * 1000)
})
```

```html
<h1 class="name" id="text"></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use innerHTML with **=**, it replace new value.

So, 'text' element's innerHTML will be changed Saab->Volvo->BMW.

It's last word. right?

Try like this,

```
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
let i  = 0 ;
setInterval(function loop(){
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML += cars[i];
    i++;
},1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can set timer if there are car left to display

```js
<h1 class="name" id="text"></h1> html code
<script>
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
var i  = 0 ;

function displayCar() {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = cars[i++];
    if (i < cars.length) {
        setTimeout(displayCar, 4000)
    }
}

setTimeout(displayCar, 4000)
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

```js
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
var i  = 0 ;
setInterval(function (){
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = cars[i];
i++;
i = i%3;
}, 4000)
```

```html
<h1 class="name" id="text"></h1>
```

The problem in your implementation was the `do-while` loop that iterates throught all elements at once.

If you use `setInterval` the whole function get's called every four seconds.

Comment: Please don't post your code to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time, making your answer meaningless. Just include your code right in your answer as a code snippet (the `<>` button on the toolbar).

Answer (score 0):

```js
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
var i  = 0 ;
function loop() {
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = cars[i];
    if (++i < cars.length) {
        setTimeout(loop, 4000);
    }
};

loop();
```

```html
<h1 class="name" id="text"></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an incremental timeout for different text. They will print in the different `timelines`.

```js
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
    cars.forEach((car, index) => {
      setTimeout(function loop() {
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = car;
      }, index * 2000)
    })
```

```html
<h1 class="name" id="text"></h1>
```

If you want to learn `async programming`, You can do the same thing using `async-await`. Please have a look below example.

// Print function which prints after 1 sec.

```
  const print = (car) => {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          // Print here
          document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = car;
          resolve()
        }, 1000)
      })
    }
```

// Main function, Now consume it

```
async function main() {
  var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
  for (let index = 0; index < cars.length; index++) {
    await print(cars[index])
  }
}
main()
```

**Working sample:**

```js
const print = (car) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // Print here
      document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = car;
      resolve()
    }, 1000)
  })
}
async function main() {
  var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
  for (let index = 0; index < cars.length; index++) {
    await print(cars[index])
  }
}
main()
```

```html
<h1 class="name" id="text"></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

here are both possible solutions.
if you want to stop at the last one.
or if you want to show keep it in loop.

```html
<h1 class="name" id="text"></h1> html code
<script>
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
var i  = 0 ;
let currentIndex = 0;
let inter_ = setInterval(function loop(){
   if(currentIndex >= cars.length){
       // if you want to loop  then the following line
       currentIndex = 0;
       // if you want to stop at the last one then uncoment the following lines
      // return clearInterval(inter_);
   }

   showCar();
   
}, 4000)


function showCar(){
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = cars[currentIndex++];
}

showCar()    

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<h1 class="name" id="text"></h1> html code
<script>
    var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
    var i  = 0 ;
    const timer = setInterval(function () {
        if (i < cars.length) {
            document.getElementById("text").innerHTML += cars[i] + <br>;
            i++;
        }
        else {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, 4000)
</script>
```